# API for getting daily billing/cost in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there an GCP API for getting daily cost breakdown by service? I need programmatic access to what Billing -> Reports shows.

Basically the analog of AWS' Cost Explorer API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Cloud Platform exposes several mechanisms for programmatically viewing and managing your costs on a day-to-day basis:

- [**Export to BigQuery**](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery) allows granular billing data to be exported periodically to BigQuery, including full details of your recent spend. This permits deeper analysis. As noted in a comment, this is (currently) the only mechanism available to you for viewing your cost breakdown.

  You would subsequently use the interactive BigQuery tools in the Cloud Console, or one of the client libraries, to query the data.
- You can set up [**Budgets**](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets) and request programmatic budget alerts be pushed to you in real-time if a certain threshold of your budgeted expenditure is reached. Such alerts are delivered over Cloud Pub/Sub. Guidance: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify

---

- **Cloud Billing API** provides REST and RPC-based APIs for interacting with metadata about your billing account. However, *it does not expose the specifics of your recent expenditure*. Documentation: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/apis

Comment: Actually, as far as I know the billing API does not contain any information on prices and spend, but mostly management information on the account and services used per account. I think the only way to get billing information using programmatic access is the export to big query and using the client libraries.
https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/cloud-client-libraries

Comment: @Dvir669 Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited the answer.

Comment: @CosmicOssifrage Thanks.  I added my support for costing API feature and Google is supposedly working on it, but no ETA.  I think it had 6 stars in their feature tracking system.

Comment: @ODYN-Kon That's good info, thanks. Have you got a link to the request in their feature tracking system? It's good info to edit into the answer.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to what Cosmic Ossifrage mentioned, you can export the usage detail into csv files in a storage bucket. Those files can be accessed with gsutil and processed by scripts.

```
#!/bin/bash

date="$(date -u +%Y-%m-%d --date='-1 day')"

files="$(gsutil ls gs://bucketname/*$date.csv)"

total="0"

for f in $files;
do
  sum="$(gsutil cat $f | awk -F ',' \
    'FNR==1 {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { f[$i] = i } } FNR>1 {sum+=$(f["Cost"])} END {print sum}')"
  total="$(echo $sum + $total | bc)"
done

echo -n GCP consumption on $date:
printf ' $%0.3f\n' $total
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes, there is Cloud Billing API [1]. I haven't used AWS Cost Explorer API so I'm not sure if this offers the same features, but take a look to the documentation.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/billing/reference/rest/